# What could cause premature failure of a brand new alternator on my 2007 Ford Escape?

Tags: ford, battery, alternator, charging, escape

The (I believe original) alternator on my 2007 Ford Escape failed last month and was replaced with an alternator from FVP. The battery was tested and seemingly passed muster. Now, three weeks later, my car is again showing very similar symptoms - battery light on, charging voltage is below 12V. Did my three week old alternator really fail already? What could be the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your short story, I would be suspecting an intermittent break in a cable. That can kill an alternator quickly.

But if this comes and goes then other loose connections may be at fault.

Comment: Also it's not unheard of to have a defective new alternator.